# Why do people (governments) hang on to the idea of East and West?

Tags: contemporary-history, terminology

The idea of "East and West" originated in the (nowadays) Middle East during "Trojan" times. The meaning of "East and West" changed since then but the "Western" governments (and by default, Eastern countries) are still holding on to this idea.  Why is that?

Edit:
As I mentioned this idea originated in the "Middle East". The "West" was pretty much Greece those days and the "East" was nowadays "Turkey".  This idea has evolved during the passage of time, expanding and shrinking geographically.  The world is moving towards a global economy, shredding the idea of "East and West", but politically, we still see the divide.  My question is why can't the world move away from the "East and West" politically?  (I suspect the answer lies in history.)

Comment: Which specific idea?  Do you mean the use of "West" to refer to European civilization and its offspring and "East" to refer to Eastern Asian civilizations?

Comment: @DavidThornley: As you see from Tom Au's answer below, people could provide different meanings to this idea.

Comment: Someone down voted this question.  Can that person provide a reason?

Comment: I'm not that person but I'll downvote it and explain why. It's incredibly wooly-headed thinking. 'Greece' and 'Turkey' were *both* Greece in antiquity; the division was between Greece and the Persian Empire; then Rome and Parthia; then Christendom and the Caliphate; then Europe and the Ottomans, Muslim India, and the Chinese Empire. Each of those was more about their own separate eras than any consistent East/West division. Similarly, there's Latin/Greek Christianity; Western/Slavic Europe; 'Free'/Communist Europe.

Comment: Those divisions aren't about any immutable 'Western' or 'Eastern' essence, but about the actual locations of separate cultures, divided by Eurasia's geography. (As far as why Eurasia has mattered more than the N/S orientation of the Americas or Africa, start off with *Guns, Germs, & Steel* and work from there.)

Comment: Also, neither Greece proper nor Greek Anatolia are the 'Middle East' by anyone's reckoning; the geographical concept being described originated in Greece, not Mesopotamia; and it had absolutely nothing to do with 'Trojan times' but Persian wars almost a millennium later.

Comment: **All in all, it's a pretty terrible question** that should be rewritten to focus on why an East/West division has begun to be reused despite Said's *Orientalism* making a mockery of the old trope and the collapse of the Soviet Union and its satellites. **The answer to *that* question would be that China has risen dramatically** and is offering an entirely separate programme of world and national governance to that upheld by the democratic, free-trade capitalists based in Western Europe and its former colonies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main factor is here undoubtedly Christianity. The Ancient Greeks may have distinguished themselves from the eastern Persians, but they did not align themselves any more with the barbarian tribes in most of Europe at the time. In fact, they at least appreciated the civilisation of the Achaemenid Persians. Other factors, most notably the Roman Empire and it successors the Byzantine and Holy Roman Empires contributed to uniting Europeans as a single entity.

The partitioning of the world in this sense started after the growth of Christianity really, and properly after the rise of Islam. **In all fairness the "West" is really synonymous with the European Christian world, which happens to lie mainly in the west of the Old World. The "East" refers to the non-Christian, predominantly Muslim, Hindu, and Chinese/Oriental regions.** Africa usually isn't included in this, due to the lesser role the continent played in world religion and politics for the most part, and never really posed a threat to European religion or culture (unlike e.g. the Arabs or Turks).

During the Middle Ages, the fierce wars between Christian European nations and the "East" in the form of religious Crusades in the Levant, and notably the Mongol invasions of much of Eurasia *except* Central and Western Europe only increased the view of Westerners and Easterners mutually as strange foreigners, and often enemies. In essence, a combination of religion, conquest (imperial rule), culture, and ethnicity led to increasing separatism between the "West" and the "East". It has however interesting to note that these factors unified European/Western nations rather more than they did the Asian nations, arguably for obvious geographic and historical reasons.

Now, historically the majority of Christians were based in Europe and specifically controlled by Rome (the Catholic church) -- very much towards the West of the Old World when considered as a whole. The colonisation and Christianisation of the Americas by the Spanish, Portuguese, French, and English, only helped solidify this geographic barrier. Sure, Australia/New Zealand sort of broke it, but they're still considered "Western" nations because of their religious and cultural heritage. **Hence, the term is largely cultural and socio-political these days, rather than geographic.**

Comment: I don't fully agree with the Christian concept as being that which ties the West together, although I don't have a better definition and I think you are far closer to the answer than Tom is.  In some ways I think of this as part of the Byzantine split to East and West but I believe the thinking was in place before then, but I have no sources to back me up.

Comment: The Christian basis may not the whole reason, though it does offer an awfully accurate partition. Cultural (Greek/Roman-influenced nations) and geographic factors also have a role to play. As do ethnic ones even.

Comment: Updated answer... hope it's clearer now. :-)

Comment: Very much so, I agree with this more now than I did before.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: I have to divide my comment to two parts as there is no room for the full comment within the character limit of a comment.

Part 1:
I tend to agree,conditionally, with this view.  Few years ago most of the countries were divided into 3 categories as the Western Block (US, UK, France, West Germany etc.), the Eastern block (USSR, East Germany, Czechoslovakia, Hungary etc.) and the Non-aligned (India, Yugoslavia, Argentina, Brazil etc.).  As winners of the "cold war", Western Bloc seems to be in the "us" against "them" mode now, that is, divide the world to only two categories; East and West.

Comment: Part 2: 

The rhetoric during the cold war seems to support your idea as non-religious "commies" were the East.  This might also explain the tolerance of Neo-Nazi regime of South Africa in the 70s.  See [Basil D'Olivera Affair.](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/356092.html) I will accept your answer, until there is a better answer.

Comment: The main factor isn't Christendom at all, given that Russia and its satellites never count.

Comment: @Sony, no, the world isn't divided into us v them, East v West. [The **actual** world strategy at the Pentagon is concerned with the 'Core' and 'Gap'](https://www.esquire.com/news-politics/a1546/thomas-barnett-iraq-war-primer/), [along with attempts to neuter Russia and China](https://fpif.org/the-pentagon-is-planning-a-three-front-long-war-against-china-and-russia/). Neither of those is 'the East'. That term may describe the Sinosphere or China as a second superpower, but no one wants to write off Japan or America's other eastern allies.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that's because the Pacific Ocean is the world's largest body of water, and hence, the hardest to cross. (The Atlantic is the world's second largest body of water).

There is a large continental mass which I refer to as "EuroAsAF" that contains the majority of the world's people. Within this large land body, it's easy to characterize "east" and "west."

The Americas are a bit trickier. One can consider them part of the "west" (in relation to "EurAsAF") or "east," in relation to the same. In the end, it appears that the reason that America is part of the "west" is because the Atlantic is still smaller than the Pacific, making it easier for the Europeans to cross it and colonize "America" than was the case for the Asians of "EurAsAf."

Comment: I think it's simpler than you are presenting, and basically that many of these terms are EuroCentric. So Asia is the Far East while Europe, and by extension America, is the West.

Comment: @MichaelF: But I (an Asian-American) have heard Asians used east and west in the same way. So I believe it may have something to do with the land mass issue. In China for instance, "east" and "south" are "good," while "north" and "west" are "bad." (Which is understandable if you look at what's north and west of China.)

Comment: I've heard the same from my wife's family (who are Chinese) and they may alternately refer to us as either direction but in general America they considered a Western nation. From the people who have come from China, when I have talked about this, is they look at Europe as the West and America as an extension of it. Chinese media, although it's hard to tell from translation, often refers to America as the West. It always confused me since we could be East as well, but it's just not used much.

Comment: Your "EuroAsAF" is better known as "The Old World" I think. ;-)

Comment: I disagree with this answer, since it ignores the huge cultural factor.

Comment: @Noldorin: Old World is a good name. But I was referring to the geographical issues. "Huge cultural factor" derives from the fact that Europeans settled "America" and Asians didn't. China supposedly discovered California in 1421, 71 years before Columbus, then got "cold feet" and destroyed its fleet.

Comment: @Tom AU: I argue that the cultural difference was very big even in the Middle Ages. Ever since the Arab Conquests, Turkey/Lebanon and eastwards, as well as North Africa were disunited from Europe culturally and religiously, losing the Roman/European influence. The Byzantines generally lost control too, so no political unity. (Except for brief periods by Venice and the Crusader States.)

Comment: Also, there is *very* poor evidence for this Chinese discovery... It is possible, but it is not generally accepted. Same goes with Jewish/Roman discoveries of America. First discoverer from Old World = Eric Leifsson with Vikings, Second discoverer from Old World (1st of Central/South America) = Christopher Columbus with Spanish. I think most people accept this

Comment: @MichaelF The Americas *are* the far east on any native Chinese or Japanese map. They both center world maps on Australia. It doesn't make any difference about the cultural reality that America is part (and currently leader) of the *Western* world.

Comment: Actually @Noldorin his EuroAsAf is usually called '[Afro-Eurasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afro-Eurasia)'. It's called the 'Ecumene' in reference to Ptolemy's geography; the 'Old World' in reference to the Age of Discovery; and the 'World Island' by some Cold War strategists.